# How to communicate with an Arduino circuit using a web app?

Tags: web, web-applications, bluetooth, arduino

I have recently made a Arduino circuit as shown in the link below:
http://www.instructables.com/id/DC-Motor-Control-With-Bluetooth/

As you can see, the person in the video of the above link used a bluetooth controller app to control and send signals to the Arduino board via HC-05 bluetooth board.

Here's the question. How can I use a web app/ web instead of a native app(like the video) to control and send signals to the Arduino board?

Comment: Ditch the Arduino hardware and get an ESP8266 board (NodeMCU, Wemos D1 Mini).

Comment: @Jason accept and upvote an answer if you think it should help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

It would require the use of additional hardware. It is for connection to the network or broadly web.

Once we consider this we have several options infront of us :

1. We can use a gsm module. In this hardware we would insert a sim and use  its network for connecting to web. But when you buy a GSM module be sure that it got http services as some modules support only message services. ( I would suggest GSM sim 900A module).
2. We can use a wifi hardware. This would act just same way as wifi on our mobile or laptop. But it requires some hotspot in its range thus restricts portability.
3. We can connect an ethernet cable to the arduino module and use the network. But thus restricts portability more than wifi. But you can go for that to if that satisfies your need.

Once you get the network for connecting to the web, now comes the point where your device must listen on the web for the requests that come to the device and must act as the inputs. We call it creating a server. The server listens on web and respond to them. As for a beginning you can follow [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebServer) article.

Comment: Is there any method that no additional hardware is needed? Can I use some Javascript language to do the connection? Is the web bluetooth developed by Google useful?